# Informar uma data, e pegar o intervalo da semana do mês dessa data (de domingo a sábado)

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Estou precisando de um comando SQL (SQLite para android), que retorne o intervalo de uma semana (de domingo a sábado) de uma data informada. Por exemplo: informo a data '05-05-2016', daí o comando em sql me retornaria o intervalo '01-05-2016' e '07-05-2016' (de domingo a sábado) que corresponde a semana da data informada. Outro exemplo (para ficar mais claro ainda kkkk), informo a data '01-04-2016', dai a função em sql me retornaria '27-03-2016' e '02-04-2016' (que corresponde de domingo a sábado, da data informada).

Comment: Seria mais ou menos isso? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76146/mostrar-todos-os-dias-entre-duas-datas/76150#76150 . Esse exemplo aqui é em SQL-Server.

Comment: Não seria isso Marconi, preciso somente da data de inicio de uma semana (domingo) e a data do fim dessa semana (sábado). Como no exemplo, que citei... informo '05-05-2016', dai tenho o retorno '01-05-2016' e '07-05-2016' (primeiro dia da semana da data informada (domingo) e o ultimo dia da semana da data informada (sábado)). Obrigado :D

Comment: Esse tipo de calculo não deveria ficar na aplicação? Pq está passando essa responsabilidade para o banco de dados?

Comment: Sou iniciante em SQL, não sei quase nada ainda, mas estou fazendo um "filtro" para pegar as datas correspondentes a semana no formato que falei (de domingo a sábado da data referida), e fazer um somatório dos dados desse intervalo de datas.

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução para MySQL passa por usar as funções `DAYOFWEEK` e `DATEADD`, por exemplo:

```
SELECT  ADDDATE('2016-05-05', INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK('2016-05-05') DAY) Domingo
       ,ADDDATE('2016-05-05', INTERVAL 7 - DAYOFWEEK('2016-05-05') DAY) Sabado
       ,ADDDATE('2016-04-01', INTERVAL 1 - DAYOFWEEK('2016-04-01') DAY) Domingo
       ,ADDDATE('2016-04-01', INTERVAL 7 - DAYOFWEEK('2016-04-01') DAY) Sabado
```

O resultado seria

```
Domingo     Sabado      Domingo     Sabado
2016-05-01  2016-05-07  2016-03-27  2016-04-02
```

Fica aí o [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a403/20)

**Solução para SQLite**

```
select DATE('2016-05-05', 'weekday 0', '-7 days') Domingo,
       DATE('2016-05-05', 'weekday 0', '-1 days') Sabado,
       DATE('2016-04-01', 'weekday 0', '-7 days') Domingo,
       DATE('2016-04-01', 'weekday 0', '-1 days') Sabado
```

Fica também aí o [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/2a403/27)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta também Bruno parece funcionar bem também, irei testa-lá.

Answer (score 1):

Uma possível solução seria essa:

Nesse exemplo a data de entrada é 19/05/2016

```
SELECT date('2016-05-19', '-6 day', 'weekday 0') as anterior, date('2016-05-19', 'weekday 6') as posterior;
```

O select retorna:

2016-05-15   2016-05-21

Comment: Obrigado Reginaldo, sua resposta funcionou!!! :D.