# Obter dados de todos os dias dos meses no range da query

Tags: sql-server

Estou com uma consulta no SQL Server que me retorna os dados de 1 atrás

```
SELECT titulo, categoria
FROM posts 
WHERE dataCadastro BETWEEN DATEADD(year,-1,GETDATE()) AND GETDATE() 
ORDER BY dataCadastro DESC";
```

O problema é que preciso que essa consulta me retorne também **todos os dados de todos os meses** no range. Eu quero que venham os resultados desde o **primeiro dia do último mês** no range até a data atual.

O problema é que estão vindo os resultados há exato 1 ano atrás então os resultados que estão vindo vem desde o dia 22/01/2017. Eu preciso que venham os dados desde **01/01/2017**.

Usar o `DATEADD` é o melhor nesse caso?

Comment: "Eu preciso que venham os dados desde 01/01/2017" Essa data é fixa? Se for, pode setar ela direto no código: `BETWEEN CAST('20170101' AS SMALLDATETIME) AND GETDATE()`

Comment: Não, não é uma data fixa. Eu preciso que sempre venha desde o primeiro dia do último mês. Se há um ano atrás é 22/01 então preciso que venha desde 01/01. Se era 15/03, preciso que venha 01/03.

Comment: Como está declarada a coluna `dataCadastro`: date? datetime? outro formato?

Comment: @DiChrist seria isso? [Como mostrar todos os dias entre duas datas?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76146/como-mostrar-todos-os-dias-entre-duas-datas/76150#76150)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Eis uma solução:

```
-- código #1 v2
-- define periodo de emissão
declare @Hoje date, @UmAnoAtras date;
set @Hoje= cast(current_timestamp as date);
set @UmAnoAtras= dateadd(month, datediff(month, 0, dateadd(year, -1, @Hoje)), 0);

--
SELECT titulo, categoria
  from posts 
  where dataCadastro between @UmAnoAtras and @Hoje;
```

A versão final depende de saber como está declarada a coluna `dataCadastro`.

---

O cálculo da variável @UmAnoAtras pode ser compreendido pelo detalhamento abaixo:

```
declare @P1 int, @P2, int;
-- calcula data de um ano antes
set @P1= dateadd(year, -1, @Hoje);  
-- calcula quantos meses desde a data 0, o que elimina os dias
set @P2= datediff(month, 0, @P1);
-- soma número de meses à data 0
set @UmAnoAtras= dateadd(month, @P2, 0);
```

É um cálculo eficiente, pois não envolve conversão de tipos.

Comment: Essa solução atende ao meu caso :)

Answer (score 1):

Uma forma de você chegar a esse dia inicial que precisa seria esta:

```
cast(cast(year(DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())) as varchar) + '-' + cast(month(GETDATE()) as varchar) + '-01' as smalldatetime)
```

Assim, sua consulta pode ficar:

```
declare @dataIni smalldatetime
select @dataIni = cast(cast(year(DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())) as varchar) + '-' + cast(month(GETDATE()) as varchar) + '-01' as smalldatetime)

SELECT titulo, categoria
FROM posts 
WHERE dataCadastro BETWEEN @dataIni AND GETDATE() 
ORDER BY dataCadastro DESC";
```